# Зачем нужен JNIEXPORT?

Tags: jni, java, c

```
JNIEXPORT 
jint JNICALL Java_com_example_sample_SampleView_getLevel
(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls) 
{
    return level;
}
```

Вне зависимости от того, есть ли JNIEXPORT или его нет, у меня все работает правильно. Тогда зачем он нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сделано, чтобы в зависимости от конфигурации можно было подставлять дополнительные модификаторы для функции и сообщить что-либо компилятору. Вам не следует беспокоиться о том, что внутри, но вы должны везде его использовать.